# CodeIgniter Edit records buttond doesnt work

Tags: php, codeigniter, edit

Started working with CodeIgniter, and when I press to edin posts I get error 
"Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster."

I changed everything, starting from controller, model and view but nothing heppend and I dont know where I made mistake

**Posts Controller**

```
<?php


class Posts extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();   
        $this->load->library('upload');

    }

    public function index($offset = 0){

        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'posts/index/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('posts');
        $config['per_page'] = 3;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'pagination-link');

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['posts']= $this->Posts_model->get_posts(FALSE,$config['per_page'],$offset);

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function view($mjestoOdredista=NULL){


        $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($mjestoOdredista);
        $post_id = $data['posts']['id'];
        $data['comments'] = $this->comment_model->get_comments($post_id);




        if(empty($data['posts'])){
            show_404();
        }
        $data['id'] =$data['posts'];

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/view',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function create(){
        //check if user is logged in
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');
        }

       $this->form_validation->set_rules('mjestoPolaska', 'Mjesto Polaska', 'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('mjestoOdredista', 'Mjesto Odredista', 'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('datumPolaska', 'Datum Polaska', 'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('datumPovratka', 'Datum Odredista', 'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('cijena', 'Cijena', 'required');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('brojMjesta', 'Broj mjesta', 'required');
      // $this->form_validation->set_rules('opis', 'Opis', 'required');
      // $this->form_validation->set_rules('post_image', 'Image', 'required');

        $data['title'] ='Create Posts';
        $data['categories'] = $this->Posts_model->get_categories();



        if($this->form_validation->run()===FALSE){

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/create',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }else {

            //upload image
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '2048';
            $config['max_width'] = '500';
            $config['max_height'] = '500';

            $this->load->library('upload');


            if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
                $error=array('error'=>$this->upload->display_errors());
                $post_image='noimage.jpg';
            }else{
                $data = array('upload_data'=>$this->upload->data());
                $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            }
            $this->Posts_model->create_post($post_image);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('post_creted', 'You post has been created') ;
            redirect('posts');
        }

    }

    public function delete($id){

        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');
        }


        $this->Posts_model->delete_post($id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_deleted', 'You post has been deleted  ') ;
        redirect('posts');
    }



    public function edit($slug){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');
        }

        $data['mjestoOdredista']= $this->Posts_model->get_posts($slug);

        //Check if user is logged in
        if($this->session->userdata('user_id') != $this->Posts_model->get_posts($slug)['user_id']){
            redirect('posts');
        }

        $data['categories'] = $this->Posts_model->get_categories();

        if(empty($data['slug'])){
            show_404();
        }

        $data['id'] = 'Edit Post';
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/edit',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }


    public function update(){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
            redirect('users/login');
        }

        $this->Posts_model->update_post();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('post_updated', 'You post has been updated ') ;
        redirect('posts');

    }

    }

?>
```

**Posts Model**

```
<?php


class Posts_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();

    }

    function get_posts($mjestoOdredista=FALSE, $limit = FALSE,$offset = FALSE){
        if($limit){
            $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
        }
        if($mjestoOdredista === FALSE){

            $this->db->order_by('posts.id','DESC');
            $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = posts.category_id');
            $query=$this->db->get('posts');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query=$this->db->get_where('posts', array('mjestoOdredista' => $mjestoOdredista));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    //Kreiranje post
    public function create_post($post_image){
        $mjestoPolaska = url_title($this->input->post('title'));
        $data=array(
                'mjestoPolaska' => $mjestoPolaska,
                'mjestoOdredista' => $this->input ->post('mjestoOdredista'),
                'datumPolaska' => $this->input ->post('datumPolaska'),
                'datumPovratka' => $this->input ->post('datumPovratka'),
                'brojMjesta' => $this->input ->post('brojMjesta'),
                'cijena' => $this->input ->post('cijena'),
                'opis' => $this->input ->post('opis'),
                'category_id'=>$this->input->post('category_id'),
                'user_id' =>$this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'post_image'=>$post_image

        );

        return $this->db->insert('posts',$data);
    }

    //Brisanje posta
    public function delete_post($id){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('posts');
        return true;
    }


    //editovanje posta
    public function update_post(){
        $slug = url_title($this->input->posts('title'));
        $data=array(
                'slug' =>            $slug,
                'id'=>               $this->input->posts('id'),
                'category_id'=>      $this->input->post('category_id'),
                'user_id' =>         $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
                'mjestoPolaska' =>   $this->input->posts('mjestoPolaska'),
                'mjestoOdredista' => $this->input ->post('mjestoOdredista'),
                'datumPolaska' =>    $this->input ->post('datumPolaska'),
                'datumPovratka' =>   $this->input ->post('datumPovratka'),
                'cijena' =>          $this->input ->post('cijena'),
                'brojMjesta' =>      $this->input ->post('brojMjesta'),
                'opis' =>            $this->input ->post('opis'),
                'post_image'=>       $post_image   
        );
        $this->db->where('id', $this->input->posts('id'));
        return $this->db->update('posts', $data);

    }

    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->order_by('name');
        $query = $this->db->get('categories');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_posts_by_category($category_id){

        $this->db->order_by('posts.id','DESC');

        $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = posts.category_id');
        $query=$this->db->get_where('posts',array('category_id'=>   $category_id));
        return $query->result_array();

    }

}



?>
```

**Edit View**

```
<h2><?= $title;?></h2>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>


<?php echo form_open_multipart('/posts/edit');?>
<?php echo validation_errors();?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mjesto Polaska</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjestoPolaska" placeholder="Mjesto Polaska">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mjesto Odredista</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mjestoOdredista" placeholder="Mjesto Odredista">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Datum Polaska</label>
                     <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="datumPolaska" placeholder ="Datum Polaska" >
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Datum Povratka</label>
                     <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="form-control" name="datumPovratka" placeholder="Datum Povratka">
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                <label>Cijena</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cijena" placeholder="Cijena">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
              <label for="select">Broj slobodnih mjesta</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="select", name="brojMjesta">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                  </select>
                </div>


            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Kategorije">Kategorija</label>
            <div>
            <select name="category_id" class="form_control">
            <?php foreach($categories as $category):?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['id'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
             <label>Postavi sliku:</label>
             <p><b>samo oni koji nude prevoz nek postave sliku svojeg vozila</b></p>
             <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
              <label>Opis:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="opis"></textarea>
            </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>

            </div>
    </div>
```

**.htaccess file**

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Probably an issue with the url, check the url and extension you are typing. Also check the base_url in the config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your htaccess file with this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CS/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /CS/index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: No, doesnt work for me. 
I think it's somewhere error in my code

Comment: Ok bro :) 
no problem :)

Comment: ifu you want button then use <a> tag like this  <a href="base_url('posts/edit/slug_value')">Edit Post</a>

Comment: Now, I think I have problem with base_url
In my adress bar i get this http://localhost/CS/posts/posts/edit
So two time posts/posts

Comment: base_url should reffer up to your project root folder.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but when I press Edit button I get this address
http://localhost/CS/posts/posts/edit

Comment: change your base url in config file

Comment: What to put inside base_url
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CS';

Comment: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: can you please upload your htaccess file i thik there is problem

Comment: You can check above in my post after Edit_View